# Add custom Nameservers for Subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, nameserver, gmail, mx

Is it possible to add custom Nameserver for my Subdomains?

For example:
My main domain example.com uses MX record from Gmail. Then my subdomain subdomain.example.com needs to use MX record from Office365.

Is it possible to achieve that by adding different Nameserver for subdomain.example.com so it can use different MX record?

Or let's just say I want to completely separate the subdomain.example.com's nameserver from my main domain for some reasons. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

A majority of your web hosts offer this with the domain manager of your web hosting package.  You usually can assign your subdomains as you please with different DNS records, CName, and A Record.

As for doing it, I would suggest that you ask your web host if it is possible first and then ask how you can do it.

Comment: Correct. It is possible, but your DNS provider for your domain name must support defining these type of records.

Comment: I'm using third party DNS Manager from zoneedit.com for one of our servers. I also uses pointhq.com for the other sites. I guess I will experiment on pointhq.com first since our main site's DNS Manager is on zoneedit.com. Thanks for the advice.